# Resetting CSS box-sizing: universal selector vs .box class

Tags: css, performance, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the performance impact of CSS's universal selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951997/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-csss-universal-selector)

I'm using the [`box-sizing`](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) property on my stylesheets because it makes everything much easier to lay out.

The way I do it is I make all elements that are fundamental to the layout `class="box"`, and I reset the `.box` class to `border-box`. My reasoning being that it's best practice to be as specific as possible. But I recently saw someone use this:

```
* { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
    box-sizing: border-box;         
}
```

This is ideal in that it resets *all* elements and takes 0 back-end fiddling, but would it be a bad idea in terms of performance? Just how expensive is a universal selector for an entire document?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that using `box-sizing` will break your site in IE7 and earlier.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is already broken in IE8 (you didn't include `-ms-` prefix). As for IE7 and earlier @Spudley, you could try [this polyfill](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill).

Comment: @bfrohs Thanks for the heads up. I checked and I think IE8 now accepts it without the `-ms-`, but it's probably still worth adding just in case. -- As for IE7 and earlier... for my own personal site, I just don't bother. For anything else, I've been going with a separate simpler stylesheet for now because I don't know enough about the older browsers to figure out how to appease all of their quirks.

Comment: @fakaff, one thing I've learned over the years: **people don't update software**. So assume the worst :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The universal selector is the most expensive selector you can use in terms of performance.

Benchmarks here: http://perfectionkills.com/profiling-css-for-fun-and-profit-optimization-notes/

But that said, it depends what you mean by "performance". If your site is noticeably slow, there are likely other reasons than your stylesheets, unless they're *really* badly written.

Comment: So since I literally never use it, it looks like one instance of `*` shouldn't impact performance too much, right? - Also, I was not aware of the right-to-left parsing. That changes a lot of my preconceptions.