# What is the practical performance impact of the * css selector?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the performance impact of CSS’s universal selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951997/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-csss-universal-selector)

Ive read that using the * CSS selector isnt ideal as it takes longer to process. However how much is this really an issue? How much longer will it take a page to be displayed if I have the following in my CSS?

```
#div1 *,
#div2 * {
float: none !important;
width: auto !important;
height: auto !important;
text-align: left;
position: static !important; 
}
```

It seems to me that the connection speed and number of large assets like images is going to make far more of a difference. The work im doing is for mobile optimization but the page size (due to various libraries) is around 750KB and there is nothing I can do about this.

As a side note im aware that using !important isnt ideal too but the messy code ive inherited means its required in this case.

Comment: This feels like premature optimisation: Eliminating or reducing large assets will make much more of a difference. Keep in mind that on mobile you're processor and memory constrained, so the less work you make the browser do, the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Read this article.](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/)

> The key to optimizing CSS selectors is to focus on the rightmost
>   selector, also called the key selector (coincidence?). Here’s a much
>   more expensive selector: A.class0007 * {}. Although this selector
>   might look simpler, it’s more expensive for the browser to match.
>
> Because the browser moves right to left, it starts by checking all the
>   elements that match the key selector, “*“. This means the browser must
>   try to match this selector against all elements in the page.