# Using Css to display text for certain conditions

Tags: html, css, xml

Given the Xml below which I cannot change, is it possible to have the conditional results with just one css file. I can only one css at the moment but css is very limited in terms of conditions from my understanding.

CASE 1:

```
<doc>
<story>
<c1><p><text-web-group class="MajorEvent"><text-web class="MajorEvent">Sample Text C1</text-web></text-web-group></p></c1>
</story>
</doc>
```

CASE 2:

```
<doc>
<story>
<c1><p><text-web-group class="MajorEvent"><text-web class="MajorEvent">Sample Text C1</text-web></text-web-group></p></c1>
<c2><p><text-web-group class="MajorEvent"><text-web class="MajorEvent">Sample Text C2</text-web></text-web-group></p></c2>
</story>
</doc>
```

CASE 3

```
<doc>
<story>
<c2><p><text-web-group class="MajorEvent"><text-web class="MajorEvent">Sample Text C2</text-web></text-web-group></p></c2>
</story>
</doc>
```

- CASE 1. **Sample Text C1** is displayed if there is text only in C1/p/text-web-group/text-web
- CASE 2. Only display **Sample Text C1** is displayed if there is text in both C1/p/text-web-group/text-web and C2/p/text-web-group/text-web
- CASE 3. **Sample Text C2** is displayed if there is a text only in C2/p/text-web-group/text-web

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Current CSS specifications do not allow you to do what you want. The way your XML is organized doesn’t allow you to style using [:empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) and you’ll require targeting a parent, something (probably) coming in [CSS Selectors Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#relational) available in no browser today.

Comment: @LeBen, you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way with only CSS. According to your explanation, you can use the following CSS:

```
story > *:first-child + * > p > text-web-group{
    display: none;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2vnsucp/)** (*change html to check*)

PS: If you have more tags like `c1`, `c2`, `c3` etc as siblings then use `~` (*sibling selector*) instead of `+` (*adjacent selector*) in the above code.

Note: Using *universal selector* `*`, as I did will [effect the performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors). Not in [modern browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13432169/1577396) though.

Comment: no doubt that works correctly, but would you have have solution if there different tags between story and c1.

Comment: @jay.james.666 if you know the depth, then you can use `>` as I did above. if you don't know the depth, then it is not possible with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Current CSS specifications does not allow you to do what you want.

Sadly the way your XML is organized does not allow you to use the pseudo-class [:empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) to style (hide) the “Sample Text C…”.

Also you’ll require targeting parents to hide `<c1>` or `<c2>`, something (probably) coming in [CSS Selectors Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#relational) but not available in any browser today.