# H1 causing a gap between divs

Tags: html, css

There is a gap between `.heads` and `.container1` that has something to do with the `h1` tag. Tried without h1 and it works, however i need the h1 there though.

How would i go about removing the gap between `.heads` and `.container1`?

http://codepen.io/techagesite/pen/Nqxzvg

```css
.heads {
  background-color: #FF9000;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #FFC223;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-bottom-right-radius: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: none;
}
h1 {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Tekton Pro;
  color: #71A00E;
}
.container1 {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #006699;
  background: #0A3D5D;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  clear: both;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: none;
  border-top-left-radius: none;
}
p.normal {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: tahoma;
  color: #F7DF57;
}
```

```html
<div class="heads">
  <h1>Some heading in here</h1>
</div>
<div class="container1">
  <p class="normal">Some text in here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: h1 is adding bottom margin.. so remove margin of h1..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, add `margin:0;` on h1

```
  h1 {
            padding: 0;
            font-size:20px;
        font-family:Tekton Pro;
        color:#71A00E;
          margin:0;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove `margin` from `h1` element:

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Strongly suggest to read about `h1` element [**here**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h1.html) and [**Collapsing margins**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) too.

[**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOdKyM)

Answer (score 3):

The gap is caused by [margin collaspsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins). In summary, the bottom margin of h1 is collapsed with that of the head element. Note that The top margin is not collapsed because there is a border between the margin of head element and the margin of h1.

You can use various techniques to *contain* the margin. The simplest one is to use `overflow: hidden` (in this example you can add a bottom border whose color matches background color).

```css
.heads {
  background-color: #FF9000;
  border: 1px solid #FFC223;
  border-bottom: none;
  /* irrelevant rules removed */
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #71A00E;
}
.container1 {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #006699;
  background: #0A3D5D;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  /* irrelevant rules removed */
}
p.normal {
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #F7DF57;
}
```

```html
<div class="heads">
  <h1>Some heading in here</h1>
</div>
<div class="container1">
  <p class="normal">Some text in here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

it will remove all extra padding and margin of all block element.

Comment: "Unfortunately, this isn't a good practice. It's very heavy on the rendering agent to apply rules to every single element in the document, especially with large web pages, and this can also destroy a lot of good default styling". [source](https://css-tricks.com/margin-0-padding-0-no-longer-cool/)

Comment: You should avoid to use the universal selector (*) because it can cause some performance issues.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida and Mehdi Brillaud : for performace issues related to the universal selector, please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951997/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-csss-universal-selector) **Impact is negligible** in most cases

Comment: @Joel Almeida using default padding and margin is not a good practice. because different browser apply different size of padding and margin.  To match the design we need to remove default padding and margin from the elements http://www.mitrax.net/webdesign/css/17-css-margins-and-paddings-problem

Comment: @RoySonasish the problem isn't the padding and margin but the universal selector. but just like web-tiki pointed out, the impact in performance is negligible, but sometimes you remove styles to buttons, submits, etc that maybe can cause you problems later.

Comment: @Joel Almeida as you check the answer I have mention that remove only default padding and margin. its also true that remove styles to buttons, submits etc that maybe can cause you problems later

Comment: @JoelAlmeida Well, it's still a bad practice since you target all elements which have no margin and padding by default. Also, using multiple techniques with a 'negligible impact' can cause a real impact in the end. So when you can avoid it, you should. There are a lot of nice resets on the web so i can't see any reason to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I just add a display property of inline-block to the h1 or p element and it removes all the div gaps.

Comment: Please consider adding code/example and better explaining your proposed answer in respect with the question.