# How to Select Multiple Elements inside a div for CSS

Tags: html, css

This may seem like a really simple question that can be answered by Google, but I have been struggling to figure this out for a while. Say you have an HTML code like this:

```html
    <p> text 1 </p>
    <div class = "divone">
        <p> text 2 </p>
        <h1> text 3 </h1>
    </div>
```

and if I have CSS setup like this:

```
    .divone h1, p{
        color: yellow;
    }
```

It seems to change the p element outside of the div element. What can I do to select the elements inside a div so that it only changes the p inside the div "divone"?

Comment: none of the answers below say this but you can also use a universal selector to select all child elements of an element - `.divone * {}` or `.divone > * {}` if you only want direct children.  Be careful if using it though as it can be an expensive selector ([although not too much in modern browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951997/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-the-universal-selector))  - which is why I haven't put this as an answer. [More information about the universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)

Comment: @Pete But it's not the same as `.divone h1, .divone p` and you will have lot's of issues with that. In my experience it's better not to use it.

Comment: @Justinas Can you expand on "lot's of issues" like what?  I've never had a problem using it

Comment: @Pete E.g. You have modal inside `.divone`, then you need to overwrite background color to be different, but it happens that `#container .divone` has higher priority than `.modal`, so you start to use `!important`... and so on...

Comment: @Justinas I've never needed to use `important` with a universal selector - that must be just you not understanding how to use css properly - it's all about specificity and would work in exactly the same way as divone p and divone h1.  Any other issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`,` separates rules, so you must repeat `.divone`:

```
.divone h1,
.divone p {
    color: yellow;
}
```

---

You can use some CSS preprocessor like LESS or SASS to nest rules:

```
.divone {
    h1,
    p {
        color: yellow;
    }
}
```

but it will compile to same CSS rules.

---

Your current rule `.divone h1, p` says apply for `h1` that is inside `.divone` or any `p` element on page

Comment: Really? I swear that there was a more intuitive way to select multiple elements inside a div, huh.

Comment: @Dragonsnap With a CSS preprocessor like SASS/SCSS you can, but not with standard CSS

Comment: @Dragonsnap - we're getting close. Support for [`.divone :is(h1, p)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) is available behind an experimental flag or experimental vendor prefix or previous name [in most browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Amatches)

Answer (score 1):

p element's parent is not specified, so you should do one of this things:

```
.divone h1
.divone p {
 color: yellow
 }
```

or you can use ">" symbol, which effects direct children of element

```
.divone > h1
.divone > p {
 color: yellow
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.divone h1, .divone p{
     color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to select immediate children of a specified element. and avoid deeper nesting, use immediate selector ">"

```
.divone > h1, .divone > p {
    color: yellow;
}
```

otherwise for selecting all children of parent element use

```
.divone h1, .divone p {
     color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Please add a comment explaining how your code fixes the issue to improve this answer.

Comment: `.divone > h1` is not the same as `.divone h1`!

Comment: @Justinas, here, Question explains the immediate children of a specified element (<div class = "divone">), so used the .divone > h1 as immediate selector

Comment: @EricHauenstein I've added explanation in my answer